# Twitter - Favorite a tweet?

Tags: twitter, favorite

I have Aouth working for Twitter, and pulling in a stream of tweets, I am trying to figure out how to then Favorite one of the Tweets coming in from the stream.

I understand twitter's API give me this:
Parameters:
* id.  Optional.  The ID or screen name of the user for whom to request a list of favorite statuses.
          o Example: http://api.twitter.com/1/favorites/bob.json or http://api.twitter.com/1/favorites/bob.rss
* page.  Optional. Specifies the page of favorites to retrieve.
          o Example: http://api.twitter.com/1/favorites.xml?page=3

But that doesn't really help me in trying to implement, or I just am not sure how to approach it

Any help ?

Answer (score 2):

[POST favorites/create on twitter development site](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/favorites/create)

Comment: "Sorry, that page doesn’t exist!"

Comment: @VladislavBauer Sorry that my link from 2011 didn't work, I've updated it with the new page that I found with 2 minutes of looking.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
function Like(ScreenName, TweetID)
{
    client.rest.post('favorites/create', { screen_name: ScreenName, id: TweetID});
}
```

Something like this in JavaScript.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please format your code snippets using the built in feature of SO.